# Red minus sign is not appearing when I hit edit button

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch, cell

I did add this code to my `viewDidLoad`, the **edit** button showed up, but there is no **minus** button at the left side of the rows.

```
  self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

After swiping the row, the **delete** button shows up, but when I hit the **edit** button there is no minus sign.

What can cause the minus sign to not show up in my program?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set your table view editing mode as,

```
   [self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
```

do the above in the action method of your edit button in navigation bar.

Or just use,

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];
}
```

If you want to show the delete button, you can implement the below code.

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

     return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```

For more details [check the apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html)